# Python two lists finding index value

Tags: python

```
listEx = ['cat *(select: "Brown")*', 'dog', 'turtle', 'apple']
listEx2 = ['hampter',' bird', 'monkey', 'banana', 'cat']

for j in listEx2:
    for i in listEx:
        if j in i:
            print listEx.index(j)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is search the items in listEx2 in listEx.  If the item from listEx2 is found in listEx, I would like to know how to print the index value of the item found from listEX2 in listEx. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want `'cat'` to be found because it is contained within `'cat *(select: "Brown")*'`?

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple items in `listEx` containing the string "cat"? Do you want the index of all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `enumerate`:

```
listEx = ['cat *(select: "Brown")*', 'dog', 'turtle', 'apple']
listEx2 = ['hampter',' bird', 'monkey', 'banana', 'cat']

for j in listEx2:
    for pos, i in enumerate(listEx):
        if j in i:
            print j, "found in", i, "at position", pos, "of listEx"
```

This will print

```
cat found in cat *(select: "Brown")* at position 0 of listEx
```

Comment: Why am I always so slow? :( - Whatever, your solution is good and works.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you wrote `j` instead of `i` in the last line:

```
for j in listEx2:
    for i in listEx:
        if j in i:
            print listEx.index(i)
#                              ^ here
```

However, a better approach is to use `enumerate`:

```
for item2 in listEx2:
    for i, item in enumerate(listEx):
        if item2 in item:
            print i
```

Comment: Please don’t just catch any exception, but only look for `ValueError`. – **edit:** Thanks xD

Comment: I want to find the index of 'cat *(select: "Brown")*'.