# python find index of of item in list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python two lists finding index value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115015/python-two-lists-finding-index-value)

```
listEx = ['cat *(Select: "Standard")*', 'dog', 'cow', 'turtle *(Select: "Standard")*', 'onion', 'carrot *(select: "Standard")*']
listEx2 = ['house', 'farm', 'cottage', 'cat', 'turtle', 'computer', 'carrot']

for i in listEx2:
    for j in ListEx:
        if i in j:
            print listEx.index(listEx2[i] in listEx[j])
```

Here is what I am attempting to do.  For the items in `listEx2`, I want to find the index of the item in `listEx`, where the item in `listEx2` was found in `listEx`. I would like the script to print out the index of the item in `listEx` with the name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might need some further clarification on this!

I think you're mixing things up a bit here.

When you do `for i in listEx2:`, in each iteration, i is the value of the position in the list, NOT the index!

If you just need the index where elements occur, then why not something like:

```
for i in listEx2:
    if i in listEx:
        print listEx.index(i)
```

This will print the index of matching ocurrences, you can concatenate the value itself, of course (i).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> listEx = ['cat *(Select: "Standard")*', 'dog', 'cow', 'turtle *(Select: "Standard")*', 'onion', 'carrot *(select: "Standard")*']
>>> listEx2 = ['house', 'farm', 'cottage', 'cat', 'turtle', 'computer', 'carrot']
>>> for elem in listEx2:
        for i, tgt in enumerate(listEx):
                if elem in tgt:
                        print elem, 'in', tgt, 'at', i


cat in cat *(Select: "Standard")* at 0
turtle in turtle *(Select: "Standard")* at 3
carrot in carrot *(select: "Standard")* at 5
```